# ValueError: unknown url type: h; in urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

Here is part of my code:

```
import urllib2
def find_all(list1):
    for link1 in list1:
        p1 = urllib2.urlopen(link1)
        s1 = p1.read()
        s2 = s1.find('"ratingValue"')
        start_char = s1.find('>', s2)
        .......

m = 'http://www.tervisetrend.ee/hambaarst-Aleksei-Ratsep-MD18661.aspx'
lm = list(m)
find_all(lm)
```

When i run it, i have following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/Downloads/link_code.py", line 70, in <module>
    find_all(lm)
  File "/home/mike/Downloads/link_code.py", line 40, in find_all
    p1 = urllib2.urlopen(link1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 258, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: h
```

Why am I having this error and how can I fix that?

Note: i have run this for many times and it didn't give me an error before now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a print of `lm`:

```
lm = list(m)
print(lm)
>>> ['h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', etc...]
```

you will find that you created a list of characters.

the correct way is:

```
lm = [m]
```